# Positive value into .blade.php {{}}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to print a positive value into blade.php with the code `{{$data['short_sell_profit_loss'] }`

`$short_sell_profit_loss = "-15,000"`

its give me an error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: It looks like $data['short_sell_profit_loss'] is actually an array and not a string.

Comment: `$data['short_sell_profit_loss']` and `$short_sell_profit_loss` are two different variables, and `{{$data['short_sell_profit_loss'] }` is missing a closing bracket. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{}}` uses PHP `htmlspecialchars()` which needs string to be it's parameter.

The error indicates that `$data['short_sell_profit_loss']` is an array

You can try putting this code before returning view in controller to get an idea what kind of value is stored in that variable.

```
dd($data['short_sell_profit_loss']);
```